# Is there a way to move, scale and duplicate hidden objects with the gizmo?

Tags: modifiers

I'm using 2.80 and want to do several difference booleans on an object.  I would greatly prefer to adjust the modifier object while it is invisible so I can clearly see the results.

What I really want to do is move and scale with widgets so I can easily do so on a specific plane, then duplicate the object for another boolean.

Using the properties editor I can move it, but I haven't figured out if I can use said editor to scale on just two axes so I sort of get what I want but it is very cumbersome.

I'm new to blender so I'm unsure if there's a setting I am missing or there is some other way to achieve a smooth workflow.

Comment: You can set the subtracted object to be rendered as wireframe in its Properties > Object > Viewport Display panel.. is that acceptable?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, changing the "Display As" to "Wire" works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**
You can constrain the location, scale and rotation of the to-be-hidden object to another object, which you then manipulate to indirectly influence the invisible object.

**Preface**
Some terminology I'm using for clarification:
'*Target*' = The object that Boolean-intersects the mesh, you want to hide this but manipulate it as well;
'*Modifier*' = The object that you need to manipulate to indirectly manipulate the *Target* object.

**Constraining the Target to the Modifier object**
Create a duplicate of the *Target* object (linked(Alt-D) if you also want to edit the *Target*'s mesh, but a link is not required).
This duplicate will be the object you manipulate, the *Modifier* object.

Note that you can also just use an Empty or generally any object; I like to duplicate the object to better see what is going on.

Create three constraints on the *Target* object; **Copy Location**, **Copy scale** and **Copy Rotation**.
For **Copy Location** you will want to enable the Offset option; this will allow you to move the *Target* object away from the *Modifier* object instead of them occupying the exact same point in space.

**Copy Scale** and **Copy Rotation** should be set up correctly as soon as you add the constraint. You may need to adjust the 'Invert' options on the Copy Rotation constraint to get the *Target* to link in the correct orientation.

The target for all constraints is the *Modifier* object.

If you select both the *Modifier* and *Target* object and duplicate these(Shift-D), the *Target* copy will already have it's constraints set up to target the duplicated *Modifier*.

---

**Images for reference**
Image 1: Here you can see the setup of objects and the constraints. The *Target* is already hidden and is selected in the Outliner. Note the position of the hole in the Cube.
[image]

Image 2: Now if you move/rotate/scale the *Modifier* object, the *Target* will move/rotate/scale accordingly.
[image]